# WPF-same arc segment to consist of 2 different colors

Tags: c#, wpf

Requirement: i have to come with a voltmeter user control.

The following code draws a arc, consisting of  voltmeter ticks and values.

```
    <Path Name="Pth" Stroke="DarkGray"  StrokeThickness="2" Width="Auto"  Height="48" Canvas.Top="12">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry >
                <PathFigure   StartPoint="35,28">
                    <ArcSegment   IsLargeArc="False"
                            Size="23,75"
                            Point="200,28"
                            SweepDirection="Clockwise"
                                RotationAngle="90"/>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
```

As one one can see above, the pen used is stroke=dark gray. i am not talking about Fill property.

**A section of the arc ,however, has to be rendered in blue**(as alarm value) in response to user specified range.Any section of the arc .

The big picture is the predominant section of arc is rendered by gray pen and the alarm section is blue.

The problem as one can see above , we can assign the pen only to Path(not the arcsegment or geometry or pathfigure) and the path can use only one pen at a time .

A gradient brush won't work here as colors blend in.Here the two sections of the arc has to be clearly distinct by color from each other.

if i use two paths dividing the arc into  2arcsegments , i have to take of the various existing calculations ,which depends on the path geometry's fraction values.

what's the best approach for my case? any suggestions guys?

Answer (score 1):

Taken from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13945821/wpf-to-stroke-arc-with-two-different-brushes/13945872#13945872):

One idea could be using a gradient brush with no spacing between the color blocks.

For example:

```
<Rectangle Width="200" Height="50">
    <Rectangle.Fill>
        <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
            <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0.500"/>
            <GradientStop Color="Lime" Offset="0.500"/>
        </LinearGradientBrush>
    </Rectangle.Fill>
</Rectangle>
```

Would result into something such as:

[image]

Although I'm afraid that you might have trouble finding the correct offset for it, in case it should be calculated dynamically.

EDIT: could you show us how the arc would approximately look like?

Comment: Thanks eve. i can find the correct offset.i have not figured out how to post a image here. just think of a voltmeter with volt values. the arc i am taking about consist of those values with ticks ofcourse.